# Android tagsoup reference

Tags: java, android

I've been using `Html.fromHtml` method for displaying and styling text into an edittext or a textview. Now, I'm trying to migrate away from the html tags because they quite limited to the method implementation and can't access the attributes for the html tags.

I decided I need to implement custom tag parsing based on `Html.fromHtml` which uses TagSoup for parsing. The problem is that the library is private and not exposed with the Android SDK. I managed to get an instance of the parser using the following code and works:

```
XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser");
```

My question is : is it safe to rely on this refrection? Or just add the jar into the libs folder. I figured that if they didn't exposed the library via SDK, they probabily thinking of switching to another library or deleting it for good.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the jar, that's the safest approach :)